# Document TOC hyperlinks not working

Tags: document-library, document, hyperlink, word

So I have been having problems with documents containing hyperlinks: most don't work. I found that some setting (still not sure what) in Chrome was causing this, as hyperlinks work fine when I preview the documents while SharePoint is open in IE or Edge. No matter what I try though, I can't get internal link within a document (like a Table of Contents or a cross-reference) to work. I have tried uploading the documents as Word docs and PDFs. I have tried opening SharePoint in Chrome, IE, Edge, and FireFox. Nothing seems to work, and I can't tell whether it is the Word web-app, a setting in SharePoint, a bug, a browser issue, a permissions issue, or what. Does anyone know a fix for this issue?